# iPad: Comments are not shown any more

Tags: bug, design

Beloved Mathematicians,

Since some days the comments are not shown anymore; besides I can't place comments.  When I put my finger on the comments tag, it simply disappeares.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've received a comment to my request, but I'm not able to see it due to the forementioned reason.  Call me dull, but please answer as an answer, otherwise I'm not able to read it ...

I'm using an iPad Pro with the latest iOS.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. But in all seriousness, what's the version of your iOS, which browser are you using, are you using the mobile interface? All those questions you should answer (ideally before someone asks them) when you submit a bug report.

Comment: Solved: the new version of 1blockr blocked the comments ...  Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the request by OP, I post Asaf's comment as an answer.

It's not a bug, it's a feature. But in all seriousness, what's the version of your iOS, which browser are you using, are you using the mobile interface? All those questions you should answer (ideally before someone asks them) when you submit a bug report. – Asaf Karagila